# Specify collection type in SimpleXML annotation

Tags: java, xml, collections, simple-framework

I am using the [Simple XML library](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) to serialize a set of elements:

```
@Root(name = "items")
public class Items {

  @ElementList(required = false, inline = true, entry = "item")
  private Set<Item> items;

  public Set<Item> getItems() {
    return items;
  }

  public void setItems(final Set<Item> items) {
    this.items = items;
  }
}
```

I need the collection to be a `Set`, but at the same time it needs to be sorted - for this reason, when serializing, I use `LinkedHashSet` as the actual type of the `items`.

```
Set<Item> items = new LinkedHashSet<Item>();
items.add(...);
items.add(...);
items.add(...);
Items root = new Items();
root.setItems(items);
new Persister().write(root, stringWriter);
```

This works out just fine and the resulting XML contains the `Item` elements in the correct order.

**The problem** is with the deserialization - Simple XML sees that the type is `Set`, picks an implementation in `CollectionFactory.getConversion()`: a `HashSet`, which does not keep the order of the elements.

One way to fix it is to change the definition of `Items`:

```
  @ElementList(required = false, inline = true, entry = "item")
  private LinkedHashSet<Item> items;

  public void setItems(final LinkedHashSet<Item> items) {
    this.items = items;
  }
```

This works, but it's really against good coding practices. **Is there a way to tell Simple XML to use `LinkedHashSet`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is caused by inlining. If you don't use `inline`, simple will put all elements as childs into a set-tag. This tag contains e.g. a `class="java.util.LinkedHashSet"` attribute, what makes it possible to decide the set-implementation.

But this is impossible for an inline-collection, so simple takes a default one.

What you can do:

1. Use `private LinkedHashSet<Item> items;` as you've already written - this makes very clear what implementation you want
2. Use a constructor where you instantiate the implementation: `public Items() { this.items = new LinkedHashSet<>(); }`
3. Write a `Converter`, where you handle the deserialisation by your own (possible an overkill).

Comment: I'd really really prefer not to have implementation-specific attribute in my XML API - so the class= approach is out of question for me. Thanks for the other ones though, I will definitely try it out.

Comment: I see ... In the worst case and if all fails, you can always fall back to a Converter-implementation.

Comment: I've just found the time to try Solution 2. and it works! Thanks, accepted!